# XSL vs Regionalisation/Internationalization Number Formats

Tags: xslt, internationalization, numbers, format

Is there any regionalisation support built into XSL when it comes to formatting numbers?

At present my underlying XML contains numbers in UK/US format, for example 54321.12345.  I can do a select sum on this to give me a total in the same format.  I can format the number using format-number(54321.12345, '###,###.#####') to give me 54,321.12345.

However when I want this to run on a different region setting on my machine such as Central European countries which have the comma seperator as "." and the decimal seperator as "," I want to format my numbers in this way to give me 54.321,12345.

Is there a nice way to do this in XSL?

Thanks,

Andez

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#format-number

> The `xsl:decimal-format` element
>   declares a decimal-format, which
>   controls the interpretation of a
>   format pattern used by the
>   [`format-number`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-format-number) function.

```
<!-- Category: top-level-element -->
<xsl:decimal-format
  name = qname 
  decimal-separator = char 
  grouping-separator = char 
  infinity = string 
  minus-sign = char 
  NaN = string 
  percent = char 
  per-mille = char 
  zero-digit = char 
  digit = char 
  pattern-separator = char />
```

Comment: @Alejandro - you just beat me to it.  Thanks a lot.  Was looking on Microsoft site and came across http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256225.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I now have the following xsl:

```
<!-- define number format to use -->
<xsl:decimal-format name="european" decimal-separator=',' grouping-separator='.' />

<!-- format the number -->
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(54321.12345,'###.##0,0000', 'european')"/>
```