# XSLT regionalisation with non-English data in the underlying XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I have read [XSL vs Regionalisation/Internationalization Number Formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625330/xsl-vs-regionalisation-internationalization-number-formats).  But that is about formatting "English" (US/UK) format numbers into numbers with other decimal and thousands separators.

My issue is that I have data in the XML which is formatted in a "regional" format, (e.g. 123.456,78 for One Hundred and Twenty Three Thousand Four Hundred and Fifty Six and 78 hundredths).  I then want to use that number in a calculation.  As far as my reading of XSL documentation goes, I have to transform that number into US/UK-English, as it were, and also remove the thousands separators.  In other words, that number above would have to be rendered as 123456.78 before I could use it in a calculation.

Is there not a way that I can tell XSL that "the underlying XML is all going to have commas as decimal separator, and will have a full stop (period) as a thousands separator"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, if you want to treat a value as a number then you need the double number format (XSLT/XPath 1.0) or one of the number formats (XSLT/XPath 2.0 and 3.0) defined in the specifications. So you will need to write code to strip the thousand separators `translate(., '.', '')` and then to replace the comma with a point `translate(translate(., '.', ''), ',', '.')`.

Comment: Thanks, I was always under that impression, but was hoping I was wrong and there was an way to get XSLT to do those translate implicitly.

Comment: Or shortly `translate(., ',.', '.')`.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, that is much better, indeed.