# Number formatting in c# string.format and xslt number-format

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, internationalization, tostring

I read these things for example:

- [XSL vs Regionalisation/Internationalization Number Formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625330/xsl-vs-regionalisation-internationalization-number-formats)
- [XSLT format-number with comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758978/xslt-format-number-with-comma)
- [W3C XSLT Number Formatting](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-format-number)
- [MSDN Custom Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx)

But the combination of xslt format-number and decimal-format makes me think we specify things twice.

In c#, `ToString()` or `string.Format()` use a similar `#,###.00` type of notation. What I like about this is that the comma character means "the position of the group separator" and the dot means "the position of decimal separator". So if I'm in french culture, I still write comma to mean the group separator, but it's replaced by a [space] when formatted. All that changes is the Culture. I can set this globally. I don't have to change the string format.

```cs
    double testNumber = 1500.99;

    CultureInfo usCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US"); //Decimal separator = . Group separator = ,
    CultureInfo frCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR"); //Decimal separator = , Group separator = [space]
    CultureInfo deCulture = new CultureInfo("de-DE"); //Decimal separator = , Group separator = .

    Debug.WriteLine( testNumber.ToString("#,###.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) ); //output: 1,500.99
    Debug.WriteLine( testNumber.ToString("#,###.00", usCulture) ); //output: 1,500.99
    Debug.WriteLine( testNumber.ToString("#,###.00", frCulture) ); //output: 1 500,99
    Debug.WriteLine( testNumber.ToString("#,###.00", deCulture) ); //output: 1.500,99
```

In XSLT, format-number seems different. Initially I thought decimal-format would be the equivalent of CultureInfo in C#. But if you specify French or German stuff there, then the string format must be changed too to reflect it. So to change the output in an xslt, I have to change all occurrences of my string format, and change the decimal-format too. I could use the default decimal-format by omitting the name attribute, that's fine. But if I have 100s of numbers in my transform, I have to change 100s of string format to match the end user's locale.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-16" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:decimal-format name="usd" decimal-separator="." grouping-separator=","/>
    <xsl:decimal-format name="fr" decimal-separator="," grouping-separator=" "/>
    <xsl:decimal-format name="de" decimal-separator="," grouping-separator="."/>

    <xsl:param name="testNumber" select="1500.99"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <DefaultVal>
                <xsl:value-of select="format-number($testNumber, '#,##0.00')"/>
                <!-- output: <DefaultVal>1,500.99</DefaultVal> -->
            </DefaultVal>
            <FrVal>
                <!-- <xsl:value-of select="format-number($testNumber, '#,##0.00', 'fr')"/> 
                Error: Format '#,##0.00' cannot have zero digit symbol after digit symbol after decimal point. -->
                <xsl:value-of select="format-number($testNumber, '# ##0,00', 'fr')"/>
                <!-- output: <FrVal>1 500,99</FrVal> -->
            </FrVal>
            <DeVal>
                <!-- <xsl:value-of select="format-number($testNumber, '#,##0.00', 'de')"/> -->
                <xsl:value-of select="format-number($testNumber, '#.##0,00', 'de')"/>
                <!-- output: <DeVal>1.500,99</DeVal> -->
            </DeVal>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**What is the good way to have "culture neutral" in an xml data file (number appear like 1500.99) and use the xslt to output either US, French or German numbers?**

Do I have to create named parameters and use that in format-number? It works, but seems a bit clumsy.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-16" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- These 6 lines are global settings/definitions -->
    <xsl:decimal-format name="us" decimal-separator="." grouping-separator=","/>
    <xsl:decimal-format name="fr" decimal-separator="," grouping-separator=" "/>
    <xsl:decimal-format name="de" decimal-separator="," grouping-separator="."/>

    <xsl:param name="us_double_2decimals" select="'#,##0.00'"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="fr_double_2decimals" select="'# ##0,00'"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="de_double_2decimals" select="'#.##0,00'"></xsl:param>

    <!-- These 2 variables set appropriately once per transform according to my end user -->
    <xsl:param name="decimal_format_name" select="'de'"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="double_2decimals" select="$de_double_2decimals"></xsl:param>

    <xsl:param name="testNumber" select="1500.99"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <Val>
                <xsl:value-of select="format-number($testNumber, $double_2decimals, $decimal_format_name)"/>
            </Val>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```